# PHP set interval of a process

Tags: php, mysql

I have an API fetcher script that reads values from XML files and updates data to mysql. It updates the database everytime it's called via ajax.

Now I want to set an interval for about a day before the query gets updated. Which php function or method should I use?

I think I should make myself a little more clear, these are the steps:

1. xml file read with php
2. Echo the results.
3. --->If (mysql updated time > 24*60*60 seconds) update the db

   --->if not, do nothing.

I can't figure out how should I process the step **(3)**

Comment: you need to setup a cron job

Comment: If you find the answer to your question, the appropriate course of action is to post an answer. Please don't vandalize your own question. Also, take some time to review the [faq].

Comment: Thanks @zzzzBov, I would have done that, but in the mean time there's another answer have been posted. I'll check it and edit the question again.

Comment: Well, I'm glad you took the time and edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well! as far as i understood your question. I think you should do with SQL not with PHP.

Save **update time** in db with query of Insert. And call a stored procedure every time you update. like in MySQL:

```
Begin
    //Adding updtime column value into a Variable called @a
    select @a:=updtime from abc order by id desc limit 1;

    //DATE_ADD() is a function of MySQL to get Time after adding Hours or Minutes etc. More can be found in MySQL Manual online
    if DATE_ADD(@a, INTERVAL 24 HOUR) > now()
    then insert into abc values ('XML',now());
    end if;
End
```

You can also do it without a variable and that would be much better as

```
    if DATE_ADD((select updtime from abc order by id desc limit 1), INTERVAL 24 HOUR) > now()
```

Comment: I think this is a better approach. I'll check it asap. Thank you.

Comment: That's what friends do. You are Welcome.

Comment: ermm.. could you please explain your code a little? I'm not familiar with `@a:updtime` and `DATE_ADD` and google isn't helping much.

Comment: I am just supposing that you keep the time column name as updtime. I don't know what your table structure is but just add a new column **updtime** in your table for storing insertion time. And @a:=updtime means when we are getting values from table column so storing value directly into a @a variable. Hope that clarifies.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. I got the idea. Salam and keep up the good work.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution that I can think of is a Cron Job.

[This page will give you detailed information](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/managing-cron-jobs-with-php-2/)

Comment: Is that the only way? I don't need the file to be executed automatically, Instead I want to execute if it's called via ajax. And I don't want an update query to mysql if the file is not accessed.

Comment: A cron is the only way to start a php process without actually calling the web server

Comment: you can run a cron once day/hour/minute. the cron can call a php script that does the necessary checks.

Comment: I just figured out there's an other way. I'll save a txt file with *file_put_contents* at first named with the id of the content. then everytime the file's acccessed, I'll just have to compare the modified time with current time. If it's older than 24 hours, do not update mysql.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, om. But I'm looking for a different solution.